# Executing .vmx file using java code

Tags: java, vmware-workstation

I want to run .vmx file using java program.Basically I want to start my virtual machine on vmware workstation using java code..

Comment: Are you looking for Runtime.exec()? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered http://labs.vmware.com/flings/vix-java-toolkit
It claims

> The VIX Java Toolkit allows Java developers to take advantage of the
>   VMware VIX API. This is a powerful API that allows for performing
>   in-guest operations on VMs running with vSphere, Workstation, Server,
>   and Player. Java developers who are writing code with the vSphere/VI
>   APIs will find this particularly useful as the vSphere API does not
>   currently provide any functionality for interacting with the guest
>   operating system. In addition, this is helpful for software testing as
>   well as systems administration.